# lvalue required as left operand of assignment. What does that mean?

Tags: c, arrays, printing, operand

sorry for bothering you again, but I'm getting an error that I am not quite sure how to solve. I'm trying to make a function that prints a matrix with a set value for both ROW and COLUMN. However, when I use ROW or COLUMN inside the "for" to print the matrix, the compiler sends me this error:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I've tried reading other similar questions and trying to find out what exactly the error means in this case but I can't seem to do so.

So my question is, what does that error mean and how do I fix it?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 3
#define COLUMN 4
#define SS1 4
#define SS2 1
#define SORTED1 8
#define SORTED2 1
#define SORTED3 5



void matrixPrint (int m[ROW][COLUMN]){
        for (ROW = 0; ROW < 3; ++ROW){
                for (COLUMN = 0; COLUMN < 4; ++COLUMN){
                    printf("%4d", m[ROW][COLUMN]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessor's `#define` creates a textual substitution, not a variable. After preprocessing, your program looks like this:

```
for (3 = 0; 3 < 3; ++3){
    for (4 = 0; 4 < 4; ++4){
        printf("%4d", m[3][4]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

This is obviously invalid: you cannot assign values to constants. In C-speak, an expression to which you can assign is called `lvalue` (a value that can appear on the *left* in an assignment). That should explain the error that you see.

To fix the error, introduce two loop variables, call them `row` and `column`, and use them instead of `ROW` and `COLUMN`:

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROW ; ++row){
    for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN; ++column){
        printf("%4d", m[row][column]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: "This is obviously invalid: you cannot assign values to constants." I heard that in Fortran, you could ;)

Answer (score 0):

fix to like this

```
void matrixPrint (int m[ROW][COLUMN]){
    int row, column;
    for (row = 0; row < ROW; ++row){
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; ++column){
            printf("%4d", m[row][column]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```